# Kernel of the Radon transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-transforms, integral-geometry, integral-operators

Consider the following generalized version of the Radon transform. Let $X,Y,Z$ be compact smooth manifolds. Let $p\colon Z\to X$, $q\colon Z\to Y$ be smooth maps. Let $m$ be a fixed smooth density (measure) on $Z$.

Consider the linear operator (Radon transform)
$$R\colon C^\infty(X)\to \mathcal{M}^{-\infty}(Y),$$
where the target space denotes the space of generalized densities on $Y$, given by
$$R(\phi)=q_*(m\cdot p^*(\phi)),$$
where $p^*$ denotes pull-back on functions, and $q_*$ denotes the push-forward on (generalized) densities. One may assume for simplicity that $q$ is a submersion. Then $R$ takes values in smooth densities.

**Question. Is it known that if $\dim X> \dim Y$ then $Ker(R)$ is non-trivial, and in fact infinite dimensional?**

**EDIT:** all known to me classical Radon transforms have such a form, e. g. the Radon transform on the sphere and between real or complex Grassmann manifolds.

Comment: Is it possible to choose things so that this is the usual Radon transform? I don't see how this is a generalization of the Radon transform.

Comment: What do you mean by usual Radon transform? All classical Radon transforms I know are special cases of this construction.

Comment: For me the usual Radon transform of a (sufficiently nice) function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a function $Rf:\Gamma\to\mathbb R$, where $\Gamma$ is the set of $n-1$ dimensional hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$ and $Rf(\gamma)=\int_\gamma f$. (Or the same with hyperplanes replaced by lines.)

Comment: In my case all manifolds are compact. But you certainly can generalize the construction to non-compact $X,Y,Z$ and all spaces of functions and densities having compact support provided the map $q$ is proper (my question makes sense in that generality and still is interesting). Then your example will be a special case of this construction.

Comment: Compactness is not important; I'm interested in getting a proper mental image. Can you give a concrete example of the choices of $m,p,q,X,Y,Z$ where a more typical Radon transform (or geodesic X-ray transform) arises?

Comment: In your example $X=\mathbb{R}^n,\, Y=\{hyperplanes\},\, Z=\{(x,H)|\, x\in H\}\subset X\times Y$.  Furthermore $m$ is a measure on $Z$ invariant under all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (translations and orthogonal transformations); it is called Haar measure on $Z$ and it is unique up to proportionality. Furthermore we identify functions and measures on $Y$ by multiplication by a fixed Haar measure on $Y$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Now it makes perfect sense to me. (I would suggest giving a concrete example like that in the question itself, but it's your call.)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~eastwood/leeds.pdf) is a lecture by Mike Eastwood on the the double fibration transform with many examples.

[arXiv:0308285](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308285) is a paper proving infectivity of the double fibration Radon transform in some cases.

[Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1981-081-04/S0002-9939-1981-0601732-0/S0002-9939-1981-0601732-0.pdf) is an 1981 paper by Quinto on the double fibration transform (in a little more restricted form).

Comment: I failed to find an answer to my question in these references. Could you please point more specific places in these papers discussing the question? Thank you.