# Kernel of Radon transform in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, integral-transforms, inverse-problems, integral-geometry

Consider the Radon transform from the space of functions on the manifold of affine lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to functions on the manifold of affine 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$(Rf)(H):=\int_{l\subset H} f(l)dl,$$
where $dl$ is the $O(3)$-invariant Haare measure on the manifold of affine lines contained in $H$.

> How to describe explicitly (e.g. as the space of solutions of a differential equation) the kernel of $R$?

A reference would be most helpful.

Remark. The kernel should be infinite dimensional since $R$ maps functions on 4-dimensional manifolds to functions on 3-dimensional manifold.

Comment: I believe this is a less general version of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202527/kernel-of-the-radon-transform